# Wait until Scheduled job is finished

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have scheduled job updating list of employees every interval.

If there any requests for fetching employees, I need to wait until the employees are loaded and at most I can wait for 10 secs. Can some help me how best this can be done in multi threaded environment.

My Controller looks like this

```
@Component
@Path("/employee")
public class Retriever {
  @Autowired
  private Loader loader;

  private List<Employee> getAllEmployee(){
    // wait unitl emaployees are loaded and get employee
    return  loader.getEmployeeList();
    }

}
```

Actual Servive

```
@Component
public class Loader {

  private List<String> employeeList;

  @Autowired
  private Backend backend;

  @Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
  public void loadEmployee(){
    //call DB other system etc
    employeeList= backend.fetchEmployee();
  }

  public List<String> getEmployeeList() {
    //wait until employees are loaded 
    return employeeList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a semaphore